# Picking up items in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an Inventory system working and when I picked up an item it would go into it but I'm not sure what I changed because the item won't be picked up anymore. I'm trying to everything I can but now the only time I can add an item to my inventory is through the start function where it was initialized.

Here is the code attached to the player

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class BasePlayer : MonoBehaviour {

private List<BaseStat> _playerStats = new List<BaseStat> ();

private List<BaseItem> _playerInventory = new List<BaseItem>();

void Start () {

BaseItem _item = new BaseItem ();
BaseItem _weapon = new BaseItem ();

_weapon.ItemType = BaseItem.ItemTypes.WEAPON;

BaseItem _potion = new BaseItem();

_potion.WeaponType = BaseItem.WeaponTypes.BOW;
_potion.ItemType = BaseItem.ItemTypes.POTION;

_playerInventory.Add (_item);
_playerInventory.Add (_weapon);
_playerInventory.Add (_potion);
}

public List<BaseItem> ReturnPlayerInventory() {
return _playerInventory;
}
}
```

Here is the code attached to the item

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Avalon : MonoBehaviour {

private List<BaseItem> playerInventory = new List<BaseItem>();

public GameObject Sword;

void Start () {
BasePlayer basePlayerScript = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player").GetComponent<BasePlayer> ();
playerInventory = basePlayerScript.ReturnPlayerInventory ();
}


void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col) {
if (col.CompareTag ("Player")) {
GreatSwordAvalon ();
Destroy (Sword.gameObject);

}
}

public void GreatSwordAvalon() {

BaseItem _avalon = new BaseItem ();
_avalon.ItemName = "GreatSword of Avalon";
_avalon.ItemDescription = "Strongest sword in the game";
_avalon.ItemType = BaseItem.ItemTypes.WEAPON;
_avalon.ItemValue = 999999;
_avalon.ItemStats.Add (new BaseStrength ());
_avalon.WeaponType = BaseItem.WeaponTypes.SWORD;
playerInventory.Add (_avalon);
}

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you try to put some debug to see if it goes in your function GreatSwordAvalon? Does it enter the if(col.comparetag("Player"))? Try to figure out where it didnt work as expected

Comment: @Matriac I tried that on the GreatSwordAvalon and OnTriggerEnter2D the function gets called. I even tried making a GetKeyDown to see if that works and it gets called but still doesn't add to inventory. For some reason it only adds through the start function.

Comment: Hum are you sure your variable _playerInventory is not null? After adding the sword , did you see in it the new item? Maybe its a problem of referencing to the right list and you only get a copy for some reason

Comment: @Matriac _playerInventory shouldn't be null because when I do _playerInventory.Add (_avalon) in the start function it goes in no problem.  The second I put that piece of code anywhere that's not the start function it doesn't add it to the inventory

Comment: Its really strange hmm i really cant figure out whats your problem sorry

Comment: @Matriac I actually just figured it out.  It was only adding items from the inventory to the inventory screen on start instead of constantly checking.  Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving the problem myself.  In my Inventory Window script I have a function called AddItemsFromInventory that checks everything in the player inventory and adds it into the Inventory window.

The problem was that I had the call to the function in the start instead of the update so it constantly checks instead of just in the beginning.